# Symfony2/Doctrine - get all values from one table according to another table

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Sorry for confusing topic name, but I don't know how to write it shortly ;) I'm pretty new to Symfony2, earlier I worked a little with CodeIgniter.

I have something like this in DB:

```
games
devs: 1,2,3 // string

developers
id: 1 | name: Blizzard // int | string
id: 2 | name: Black Isle
id: 3 | name: Bethesda
...
```

I want to get all the `developers` according to `devs`. I have an idea using `explode`, but I have no idea, how to write it in Doctrine's Query Builder. Any one has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
<?php

$game = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('Game')
    ->findOneById($gameId)
;
$developers = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('Developer')
    ->findById(explode(',', $game->getDevs()))
;
```

or if you need query builder:

```
<?php

$game = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('Game')
    ->findOneById($gameId)
;
$qb = $this
    ->getManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
;
$developers = $qb
    ->select('d')
    ->from('Developer', 'd')
    ->where($qb->expr()->in('d.id', explode(',', $game->getDevs())))
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute()
;
```

but probably better idea is use one-to-many relation instead and rely on doctrine then ;) (Then doctrine can cache some stuff as well)

Comment: `->findById(explode(',', $game->getDevs()))` - just what I was looking for, thanks!